# How to remove "folders" links from Open and Save as dialogues?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, links, windows-8.1-preview

I have already removed the NameSpace directory from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\ to disable the links in "This PC" that appeared in 8.1, but they still appear when in an application I run the Open or Save As commands.

What other registry keys do I have to remove to be rid of these links completely?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You have to find the CLSIDs for all the links you want to remove (desktop, documents, downloads, music, pictures, videos) and then look them up in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\`

The keys will come with a value named `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree`
Change it to 0 for all the links.

These are the IDs for the links above

```
{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}
{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}
{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}
{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}
```